# Storybook can't process TS files outside of the project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have noticed that Storybook can't process Typescript files if they are from another project (monorepo), but it is doing okay with TS files that are within its project.
How do I configure Storybook to handle TS files outside the project?

Structure of the monorepo:

```
package1
    .storybook
        main.ts
        preview.ts
    component.tsx (this component imports file.ts)
    component.stories.tsx
package2
    file.ts <- (Storybook can't process this file: ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token)
```

Here is the main.ts config file:

```
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const toPath = (filePath) => path.join(process.cwd(), filePath);

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(mdx|js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs/register",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y",
    'storybook-addon-styled-component-theme/dist/preset',
    'storybook-addon-themes',
    "storybook-dark-mode",
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/react",
  "core": {
    "builder": "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
    "disableTelemetry": true,
  },
  features: {
    emotionAlias: false,
  },
  typescript: { reactDocgen: false },
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '@emotion/core': toPath('node_modules/@emotion/react'),
          'emotion-theming': toPath('node_modules/@emotion/react'),
        },
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:11)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { Palette as palette } from '../Palette';
| 
> const Paper: any = [
|     {
```

If I import the same TS file, but manually precompiled into regular JS - Storybook works.

I have no idea what to try to solve this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to .storybook/main.js

```
webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
  // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
  // You can change the configuration based on that.
  // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

  // Storybook uses its own webpack config, so we need to merge our config with it
  // See https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/

  // Add typescript loader to process TS-files from other packages
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve("ts-loader"),
        options: {
          reportFiles: [
            "../**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  });

  config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");

  return config;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same issue and it's pretty arcane. I setup my monorepo with pnpm workspaces and had a package like you where you have your storybook, just like you the parsing of typescript stories & components worked well inside of the storybook package, but when importing stories from other packages it failed to parse typescript.

In my install I'm running storybook 7.0.0-rc.8, I think this fix would work for versions below 7 as well.

Fix:
When storybook bootstraps it creates a `.babelrc` file beside the `.storybook` directory (if you tell the init script to do so).

All that was needed for me to get it working was to rename that file to `babel.config.json` (no change of content, just renaming the file).

The contents of my `babel.config.json` file:

```
{
  "sourceType": "unambiguous",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
         "targets": {
           "chrome": 100
         }
      }
  ],
  "@babel/preset-typescript",
  "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Comment: I was trying to fix this issue for hours, I saw your answer but didn't even bother trying it as I thought it was too stupid.

Well guess what?! It fucking works!! Thank you, you magnificent person!

Comment: It works! and it made me wish I was a backend engineer.

Comment: I don't know why, but it worked too...

Comment: Came across this (thanks!) and later ran across https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/babel#babelrc-vs-babel-config which explain why it works.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric ! This was mind blowing.